# DataTables row details in Ruby on Rails - how to separate HTML from Javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I am using DataTables jQuery plugin in a Ruby on Rails project (directly, not through a datatables-rails gem) and I need to display row details as explained here:
https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html

In my case, after calling `$("#table_id").DataTable()`, I use this format() function in .js file to pass data for display to the `row.child`:

```
/* Formatting function for row details */
function format(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + label_variable1 + ':</td>' +
        '<td>' + d.office.name + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + label_variable2 + ':</td>' +
        '<td>' + d.office.location + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        // Several more rows...
        '</table>';
}
```

This works fine, however it looks messy with all this HTML in the .js asset file. I want to understand if there is a way to extract the HTML (possibly in a partial).

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. Use form_for or simple_form_for to create the form in a template (make it a partial if you wish). And then in js code you just need to call `$("#table_id").DataTable()` (of course table_id is the id of your table here, and you can pass in options at the same time).

Comment: Thanks EJ2015! I was already using the `$("#table_id").DataTable()` (edited question to clarify), but still your answer pointed me to the right direction. What I ended up doing was to create the table via jQuery (similarly to how it is explained here: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/working_w_tables_using_jquery.html) and load its styling from CSS asset.